# Why my JavaScript Validation is not working?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to validate my registration form with both JavaScript and PHP. The problem is my JavaScript validation is not working. Upon clicking register button with username, password and email is empty, I don't receive any error from my JavaScript. However my PHP Validation is work fine. What is the problem with my codes?

```js
var username = document.forms['vform']['username'];
var email = document.forms['vform']['email'];
var password = document.forms['vform']['password_1'];
var password_confirm = document.forms['vform']['password_2'];
// SELECTING ALL ERROR DISPLAY ELEMENTS
var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
var email_error = document.getElementById('email_error');
var password_error = document.getElementById('password_error');
// SETTING ALL EVENT LISTENERS
username.addEventListener('blur', nameVerify, true);
email.addEventListener('blur', emailVerify, true);
password.addEventListener('blur', passwordVerify, true);
// validation function
function Validate() {
  // validate username
  if (username.value == "") {
    username.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "Usernames is required";
    username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // validate username
  if (username.value.length < 3) {
    username.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "Username must be at least 3 characters";
    username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // validate email
  if (email.value == "") {
    email.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('email_div').style.color = "red";
    email_error.textContent = "Emails is required";
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // validate password
  if (password.value == "") {
    password.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('password_div').style.color = "red";
    password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
    password_error.textContent = "Passwords is required";
    password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  // check if the two passwords match
  if (password.value != password_confirm.value) {
    password.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "red";
    password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
    password_error.innerHTML = "The two passwords do not match";
    return false;
  }
}
// event handler functions
function nameVerify() {
  if (username.value != "") {
   username.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   name_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
}
function emailVerify() {
  if (email.value != "") {
   email.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('email_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   email_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
}
function passwordVerify() {
  if (password.value != "") {
   password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('password_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   password_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
  if (password.value === password_confirm.value) {
   password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
   document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
   password_error.innerHTML = "";
   return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<?php include('server.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
  </div>
  
  <form method="post" action="register.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="vform">
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

    <div class="input-group" id="username_div">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
      <div id="name_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" id="email_div">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="textInput" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
      <div id="email_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" id="password_div">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="textInput" name="password_1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" id="pass_confirm_div">
      <label>Confirm password</label>
      <input type="password" class="textInput" name="password_2">
      <div id="password_error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="btn">
    </div>
    <p>
      Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: because you are returning after one validation

Comment: You can set one flag and can return accordingly

Comment: Try to console.log elements, also try using document.querySelector("form") to get form element

Comment: JavaScript validation is so last decade. `<input type="text" REQUIRED />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var username = document.forms['vform']['username'];
    var email = document.forms['vform']['email'];
    var password = document.forms['vform']['password_1'];
    var password_confirm = document.forms['vform']['password_2'];
    // SELECTING ALL ERROR DISPLAY ELEMENTS
    var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
    var email_error = document.getElementById('email_error');
    var password_error = document.getElementById('password_error');
    // SETTING ALL EVENT LISTENERS
    username.addEventListener('blur', nameVerify, true);
    email.addEventListener('blur', emailVerify, true);
    password.addEventListener('blur', passwordVerify, true);
    // validation function
    
    var isValidate=true;
    
    function Validate() {
      // validate username
      if (username.value == "") {
        username.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "red";
        name_error.textContent = "Usernames is required";
        username.focus();
        isValidate&=false;
      }
      // validate username
      if (username.value.length < 3) {
        username.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "red";
        name_error.textContent = "Username must be at least 3 characters";
        username.focus();
        isValidate&=false;
      }
      // validate email
      if (email.value == "") {
        email.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('email_div').style.color = "red";
        email_error.textContent = "Emails is required";
        email.focus();
        isValidate&=false;
      }
      // validate password
      if (password.value == "") {
        password.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('password_div').style.color = "red";
        password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
        password_error.textContent = "Passwords is required";
        password.focus();
        isValidate&=false;
      }
      // check if the two passwords match
      if (password.value != password_confirm.value) {
        password.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "red";
        password_confirm.style.border = "1px solid red";
        password_error.innerHTML = "The two passwords do not match";
        isValidate&=false;
      }
      return !(!isValidate);
    }
    // event handler functions
    function nameVerify() {
      if (username.value != "") {
       username.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
       document.getElementById('username_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
       name_error.innerHTML = "";
       return true;
      }
    }
    function emailVerify() {
      if (email.value != "") {
       email.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
       document.getElementById('email_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
       email_error.innerHTML = "";
       return true;
      }
    }
    function passwordVerify() {
      if (password.value != "") {
       password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
       document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
       document.getElementById('password_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
       password_error.innerHTML = "";
       return true;
      }
      if (password.value === password_confirm.value) {
       password.style.border = "1px solid #5e6e66";
       document.getElementById('pass_confirm_div').style.color = "#5e6e66";
       password_error.innerHTML = "";
       return true;
      }
    }
```

```html
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Register</h2>
      </div>
      
      <form method="post" action="register.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="vform">
        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

        <div class="input-group" id="username_div">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
          <div id="name_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" id="email_div">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="textInput" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
          <div id="email_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" id="password_div">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="textInput" name="password_1">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" id="pass_confirm_div">
          <label>Confirm password</label>
          <input type="password" class="textInput" name="password_2">
          <div id="password_error"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="btn">
        </div>
        <p>
          Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
        </p>
      </form>
```

Comment: works fine but a the problem is it disappear suddenly

Comment: Because Your Form is Submitting

Comment: what should I do? Do I change it as buttom?

Comment: I have fixed Now check

Comment: I have added this ```return !(!isValidate);```